# Microsoft GraphAPI users/delta endpoint returns 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, delta

I encountered an odd problem working with the Microsoft GraphAPI beta Delta Query endpoint for users.
The first 2 requests worked as expected, supplying a "nextLink" in the response.
Then, the last request (which was supposed to be the last, and according to documentation should have returned a "deltaLink" in the response) fails returning a 404 (non-JSON response).

Is this a known issue with the beta Delta Query?

**The request:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken={TOKEN_HERE}

**The response:**

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: The internal error message for delta?$skiptoken (404) is{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4a88a1fe-d16a-4fe1-8d2e-3f1e451e3ccf",
      "date": "2017-03-27T17:38:30"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in the API where the skip token size, hence the query string size, is sometimes large (> 256 characters) and service does not handle it. We are actively working on a fix. Please check your skip token size and let us know in case it does not satisfy above criteria.

Comment: Yes, the skipToken size is definitely more than 256 characters.
Is there an ETA on the fix?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. Let us know if you have any more issues or feedback on the capability.

Comment: Still happening to me with message syncing. Getting error: `resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title> (truncated...)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701051/message-syncing-with-microsoft-graph-api-failing

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to use the following endpoint
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}
404 - File or directory not found